# Zeppelin with Athena JDBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-zeppelin, amazon-athena

I have created an Athena interpreter using jdbc connectivity in Zeppelin and given the below configuration details

[image]

I have also downloaded Athena jdbc driver from AWS and saved in /usr/local/jars/ however when I run the query, I keep getting the error that Athena Driver can't be found. Any help on how to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem.  I managed to solve it by replacing the `default.driver` with `com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver`.